# Array to List<t> c#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, list

My current code works and output is correct. I am pulling data from a data.txt file and have successfully done so to an array using TextFieldParser. Is there a way to convert my code to a List? And how so? If converting is not an option then any recommendations on where to start with the code? Basically trying to go from an array to a list collections.

```
public partial class EmployeeInfoGeneratorForm : Form
{
    public EmployeeInfoGeneratorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // button event handler
    private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] parts;

        if(File.Exists("..\\data.txt"))
        {
            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("..\\data.txt");

            parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
            while (true)
            {
                parts = parser.ReadFields();
                if (parts == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                this.nameheadtxt.Text = parts[0];
                this.addressheadtxt.Text = parts[1];
                this.ageheadtxt.Text = parts[2];
                this.payheadtxt.Text = parts[3];
                this.idheadtxt.Text = parts[4];
                this.devtypeheadtxt.Text = parts[5];
                this.taxheadtxt.Text = parts[6];

                this.emp1nametxt.Text = parts[7];
                this.emp1addresstxt.Text = parts[8];
                this.emp1agetxt.Text = parts[9];
                this.emp1paytxt.Text = parts[10];
                this.emp1idtxt.Text = parts[11];
                this.emp1typetxt.Text = parts[12];
                this.emp1taxtxt.Text = parts[13];

                this.emp2nametxt.Text = parts[14];
                this.emp2addresstxt.Text = parts[15];
                this.emp2agetxt.Text = parts[16];
                this.emp2paytxt.Text = parts[17];
                this.emp2idtxt.Text = parts[18];
                this.emp2typetxt.Text = parts[19];
                this.emp2taxtxt.Text = parts[20];

                this.emp3nametxt.Text = parts[21];
                this.emp3addresstxt.Text = parts[22];
                this.emp3agetxt.Text = parts[23];
                this.emp3paytxt.Text = parts[24];
                this.emp3idtxt.Text = parts[25];
                this.emp3typetxt.Text = parts[26];
                this.emp3taxtxt.Text = parts[27];

            }

        } 
        else //Error Message for if File isn't found
        {
            lblError.Text = "File Not Found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var list = parts.ToList()` - it's built in System.Linq - [`ToList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why do you want to convert to a list? If the internal implementation works fine with an array I see no reason to change it,

Comment: Learning c# and starting to learn more about Collection lists. Experimenting with this project. I understand it works as an array but I am just trying to learn more into collections. I'm very green and new to programming and c#. I may have some bad practices within my code but really trying to grasp how to convert this from an array to a collection list.

Comment: Instead of `while(true)`, use `while(!parser.EndOfData)`

Comment: Your code is strange. Why does it set all the texts in a loop?  This is equivalent to simply setting the text to the *last* element, so say that.

Comment: Working with different collections is more about know when a given collection is appropriate, or more appropriate than others.  Syntax is pretty easy to find.  In your example case, you know exactly how many fields you should have, and even know the header for each one.  A list would be more appropriate when you have an unknown number of fields.  As others have stated, if you want to make the array a list after the fact for ease of use, that is simple to accomplish.

Comment: There is no point in updating these UI controls with the fields, you can only ever see the last record in the file.  Instead declare a class that can store these values and then you can declare of List(Of ThatClass).  Use its Add() method in the loop.  If you also want to see the content then consider a DataGridView.

Answer (score 2):

In your code example there are two arrays.

### First example

```
parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
```

Since `parser` is a `TextFieldParser`, I can see that [`Delimiters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.delimiters(v=vs.110).aspx) must be set to a string array. So you cannot change it.

### Second example

```
string[] parts;
parts = parser.ReadFields();
```

This array accepts the result of `parser.ReadFields()`. The output of that function is a string array, so this code can't be changed without breaking the call.

However, you can immediately convert it to a list afterward:

```
var parts = parser.ReadFields().ToList();
```

There isn't much point to this either.

An array is just as good as a list when the size of the array/list doesn't change after it is created. Making it into a list will just add overhead.

Comment: In that case, you have to pass an array to `Delimiters`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips thus far everyone! I think it might be best to not even have the array there if I want it in a collection list. But now just trying to figure out how to pull data from a .txt file and then display to more windows form. Any help would be awesome in this task but I will be looking online for some good tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here. I'd be inclined to write your code like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> ParseFields(string file)
{
  // Use "using" to clean up the parser.
  using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(file))
  {
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    // Use end-of-data, not checks for null.
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
      yield return parser.ReadFields().ToList();
  }
}
```

I'd refactor your code to put the UI updates in one method:

```
private void UpdateText(List<string> parts ) { ... }
```

You only do something with the *last* element in the sequence; all your previous edits are lost. So be explicit about that:

```
private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Use a named constant for constant strings used in several places
  const string data = "..\\data.txt";
  if(!File.Exists(data))
  {
    lblError.Text = "File Not Found";
  } else {
    var parts = ParseFields(data).LastOrDefault();
    if (parts != null) 
      UpdateText(parts);
  }
}
```

See how much cleaner that logic looks when you break it up into smaller parts?  It's very pleasant to have methods that fit easily onto a page.

Comment: Sorry for the probably dumb question Eric(But thank you as some of this makes since). I like what you are showing me here but I am very new and having a hard time right now making edits to work with your suggestions. I'm probably missing something basic. Any way you can show where and what code of mine is being replaced with your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A direct answer to your question:

Use the `List<T>` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` parameter.

With that said, I would read Mr. Lippert's answer until you fully understand it.